# Which numbers have the sum of their digits equal to the sum of the digits of their inverse?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, summation, recreational-mathematics

$n$ is a number such as $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $n >0$.*(Eg. $n = 8$)*

$p$ is the sum of the digits of $n$ in base $10$.*(Eg. $n=80$, $a = 8+0 = 8$)*

$q$ is the sum of the digits of $1/n$ in base $10$.*(Eg. $n=80$, $1/n = 0.0125$, $b = 0+0+1+2+5 = 8$)*

If $p = q$, the number is called a *cool* number.

If $p \neq q$, the number is called a *not cool* number.

The question is : **which numbers $n$ are *cool* ?**

What I found myself :

- Numbers with infinite decimals can't be *cool*.
- If $n$ is *cool*, then $n = 2^a*5^b$ with $a \in \mathbb{N}$ and $b \in \mathbb{N}$
- If $ 2^a*5^b$ is *cool*, then  $2^{a+1}*5^{b+1}$ is *cool* too.
- If $ 2^a*5^b$ is not *cool*, then  $2^{a+1}*5^{b+1}$ is not *cool* too.
- These numbers are *cool* : $1,8,10,80,100,125,800,1000,1250,8000...$

Thank you for helping in my quest for *cool* numbers.

Comment: You only need to find the base cases, and these are $2^a$ and $5^b$. But they are symmetric, $2^a$ is cool if and only if $5^a$ is cool. So you are looking for $a$ such that the digit sum of $2^a$ is equal to the digit sum of $5^a$.

Comment: To continue Daniel's comment, We must have $ 2^a \equiv 5^a \pmod{9} $, which gives us $ a = 3k$. Unfortunately, there isn't much more that we can say with digit sums.

Comment: I suspect you have found them all. $5^a$ has a lot more digits than $2^a$, so we'd expect it to have a larger digit sum, especially as $a$ increases. Compare https://oeis.org/A066001 and https://oeis.org/A001370